# Split byte array (byte[]) in 3 seperate byte variable

Tags: c#, udp

Im working on a server program that will receive a series of data from a client..Once I receive these data, I need to split them into 3 variables after every 8 bit. How can I achieve this ?These are my codes :

```
 var remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
 var data = udpServer.Receive(ref remoteEP); // data is 24bit of type Byte[]

 //=========================var conversion=================================

 //Need to split data into byte data1, data2, data3 for every 8bit

 //=========================var conversion=================================
```

Answer (score 1):

All arrays support the subscripting operator to get individual elements.  Indexing in C# is zero-based.

So your "data1", "data2", "data3" are written in code as

```
byte data1 = data[0];
byte data2 = data[1];
byte data3 = data[2];
```